# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f07007e

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-resources, android-recyclerview

I am Trying to implement like feature in the app, here is the snippet from the Viewholder in the recycled view.

Recycler customadapter

```
public class PostAdapterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

TextView title,user,description,tag,time,designation;
Long date;
ImageView imageView,bookmark,profilepic,sharebutton,like;
RelativeLayout head;
LinearLayout content;
DatabaseReference reference;
Context context;
String name;

public void setContext(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public PostAdapterViewHolder (final View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    head = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.head);
    content = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.content);
    imageView =(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageview);
    designation = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.designation);
    like =(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.like);
    profilepic = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    bookmark =(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.bookmark);
    title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
    time = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
    tag = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tag);
    sharebutton = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.sharebutton);
    user = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.username);

    like.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            ImageView i = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.like);
            Drawable a = i.getBackground();

            if (a.getConstantState().equals(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.emptyup).getConstantState())){

                i.setImageDrawable(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.fillup));

            } else {

                i.setImageDrawable(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.emptyup));

            }

        }
    });

  }
}
```

}

> 01-09 10:43:45.747 6602-6602/ctize.connectplus.com.communitize E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                    Process: ctize.connectplus.com.communitize, PID: 6602
>                                                                                    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f07007e
>                                                                                        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1397)
>                                                                                        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:843)
>                                                                                        at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:458)
>                                                                                        at ctize.connectplus.com.communitize.PostAdapterViewHolder$2.onClick(PostAdapterViewHolder.java:98)
>                                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5226)
>                                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21350)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5582)
>                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Comment: Share whole code...

Comment: Post your error logs

Comment: Share whole code and post complete error logs

Comment: @Asad Mukhtar I added error logs and more detail code for the same.

Comment: why didn`t you implement the functionality like this, and check that R file is imported or not correctly ??

Comment: it seems from your log that the issue is with drawable.

Comment: public class Example extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Example.Myholder>{

}
// Implements all override functions and do onCreateViewHolder find the layout and onBindViewHolder assigning all the values and create inner class that extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder and in that implement its method and in that place you find all id`s.

Comment: I think if you implement right way then you should get the correct way to solve your problem>..

Comment: Also check that all resources id`s are found correctly is there any is null or not and check R file is included or not check that first

Comment: @Umair yes the problem was that one of the drawable was of X24 type, changed it and it started working. but the When in the screen when clicked both the drawable is seen.

Comment: @AsadMukhtar yes the problem if fixed i changed the drawable. Thanks for help.

Comment: @Gaurav Rai rate the answer plz and welcome dear

Comment: @GauravRai so you fixed your problem ?

Comment: @Umair yes but got stuck at a weird problem, When that imageView is clicked both the drawable the previous one and the new one is seen simultaneous at the same place.

Comment: @GauravRai I believe you are also setting the background drawable to your imageView in xml file. Check there, if not then clean and rebuild your project and run again.

Comment: @Umair Ya it was the same thing, changes the XML attribute and code and it it's working as I expected. Thanks for the help.

Comment: ya sure do that @Umair

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Your app crash when the activity concerned should be displayed ?

Check if in you activity you have a drawable v24 like this
[image]

Then, if yes, change the display of your files from `Android` to `Project` at the very top of the hierarchy of your files :
From
[image]

to

[image]

And drag and drop the drawable in the directory `drawable v-24` to the directory `drawable`.

That's all. Try if it's ok

Edit : I found that the problem may arise on the Android 6 API 23 but not for higher API

Comment: Thank you sir this solved the problem that I was having with TabLayout. When I moved the v24 drawable to the other folder it worked normally

Comment: Or if your ic_launcher_background is in the values folder, then copy that color and move it to a file with colors and delete the ic_launcher_background file in the values folder

Answer (score 7):

By seeing the logs. The problem is in your `drawable` background take a look at it. You have type `X24` image change it and it will fix your problem.

Second thing is you are seeing two images at a time. So you need to remove the background that you are setting in your `.xml` file and you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `context.getDrawable(R.drawable.fillup)` which will only work in versions higher than **LOLLIPOP**. Use `context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fillup)` to get the images from resource.

Comment: Sure I will keep that in mind, make the necessary changes in the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<CheckBox android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:text="new checkbox"
 android:background="@drawable/checkbox_background" 
 android:button="@drawable/checkbox" />
```

Try to use checkbox instead of ImageView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_focused="true"
  android:drawable="@drawable/fillup" />
 <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_focused="true"
  android:drawable="@drawable/emptyup" />
 <item android:state_checked="false"
  android:drawable="@drawable/emptyup" />
 <item android:state_checked="true"
  android:drawable="@drawable/fillup" />
</selector>
```

> if
>   (a.getConstantState().equals(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.emptyup).getConstantState())){
>
> ```
>             i.setImageDrawable(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.fillup));
>
>         } else {
>
>             i.setImageDrawable(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.emptyup));
>
>         }
> ```

These lines are giving you error because of your android version issue.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources.html#vector-drawables-backward-solution, 
You should use setImageResource() instead of setImageDrawable()

Answer (score 0):

Check if the drawable resource image is in *drawable* folder, **not** *drawable-24*.
I already have this problem but solve it by moving the image resource to *drawable* folder.

Answer (score -3):

Please try a clean build, may be the R file is wrong