# Drawable doesn't display image that inserted in Callback

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-room

I'm currently building a application that takes data from database and displays the information.

I looked at those solutions but it didn't work:

[android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f07007e](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48161713/android-content-res-resourcesnotfoundexception-resource-id-0x7f07007e)

[Android ResourcesNotFoundException however image present in all drawable folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62115179/android-resourcesnotfoundexception-however-image-present-in-all-drawable-folders)

Here is my error message:

```
 Process: com.example.plantmanagement, PID: 27961
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x1
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:216)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1331)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.createDrawableIfNeeded(ResourceManagerInternal.java:176)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:141)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:132)
        at androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:104)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource(AppCompatImageHelper.java:90)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageResource(AppCompatImageView.java:98)
        at com.example.plantmanagement.adapter.Photo_Adapter.onBindViewHolder(Photo_Adapter.kt:35)
        at com.example.plantmanagement.adapter.Photo_Adapter.onBindViewHolder(Photo_Adapter.kt:17)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7065)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7107)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6012)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6279)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager.layoutChunk(GridLayoutManager.java:561)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(GridLayoutManager.java:170)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3851)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4404)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1855)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1855)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:530)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:753)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2792)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2319)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1460)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7183)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:696)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

This is how I'm trying to populate data:

```js
INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    PlantDatabase::class.java, DB_NAME
                ) 
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .addCallback(object : Callback() {
                        override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                            super.onCreate(db)
                            Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()
                                .execute(Runnable {
                                    INSTANCE?.plantDao()!!
                                        .insertAll(Plant(1,"Aloe", R.drawable.plantlogo,"Aloe","1 per week","Dangerous for pets"))
                                })

                        }
                    })
                    .build()
```

Here is how I set my Imagine in adapter:

```js
 override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        // Get the data model based on position
        var data = dataList[position]


        holder.title.text = data.name
        holder.desc.text = data.type.toString()


        holder.image.setImageResource(data.image) // Error message indicates that this line has error
        holder.relativeLayout.setOnClickListener { view -> //Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"click on item: "+model.getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            val intent = Intent(view.context, PlantDetails::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("plant_name", data.name)
            intent.putExtra("plant_image", data.image)
            intent.putExtra("plant_type", data.type)
            intent.putExtra("plant_water", data.water_time)
            intent.putExtra("plant_details", data.details)
            view.context.startActivity(intent)
    }

}
```

The data class:

```js
@Entity(tableName = "Plant")
data class Plant(

        @PrimaryKey var plant_id:Long,
        @ColumnInfo (name="plant_name") var name: String,
        //@Embedded var type: Plant_Category,
        @ColumnInfo(name= "plant_image") var image: Int,
        @ColumnInfo(name="plant_type_name") var type:String ="",
        @ColumnInfo(name="plant_type_water")var water_time: String ="",
        @ColumnInfo(name="plant_type_details")var details: String = "",


        ) {

}
```

Here is the log of data.image:

```
 data.image log: 1
```

The error message indidcaes that I didn't set Image properly  but before adding the Database I tested with the ArrayList and I didn't have any issues.

I will be thankful for your help.

Comment: I am going to guess that `data.image` is not a resource value which is required by [setImageResource()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView#setImageResource(int)). How are the elements of `dataList` defined?

Comment: can you please post logs of data.image?

Comment: Try to use glide to load images

    String url = getURLForResource(R.drawable.image);
    // Load image
     Glide.with(getContext())
              .load(url)
              .into(imageview);

Comment: @Cheticamp I added the data class

Comment: @Mr.Patel I added the log of `data.image`

Comment: @Mr.Patel It's seems `getURLForResource()`  the function doesn't exist in Kotlin.

Comment: _data.image log: 1_ shows that you are using "1" as a resource id in setting the image and this corresponds to the #0x01 in the error message. Somewhere you are putting this into your database. You don't show how the dataList is populated, but I would look there. Is the plant id getting set as the image?

Comment: I populate my dataList from Database Callback as I showed you in code. I try replace 'plant_id' from 1 to 'R.drawer.plantlogo' but it's instantly showed type mismatch because my plant_id is Long and my Image is Int. I used Int because that worked for me when I tested how the data will look in UI with ArrayList. Perhaps you want to see specific part of code because I try to populate from callback when the database is built.

Comment: @Cheticamp or would you like to see my github to understand how my code is arranged?

Comment: github might help. I only see one reference to dataList and that is where "var data" is defined.

Comment: @Cheticamp Actually nevermind I figured a problem. At first I was confused when you told me that somewhere else image set as 1 .  Then I realized I tried to populate with createFromAsset() with the database file it didn't work at first so I commented the line and tried to populate with Callback. Well apperantly the createFromAsset() started working and I confused that I was populating with Callback() and not createFromAsset() lol. Anyway I went back to the file and changed it to correct image id and it started working perfectly as I intended. Thank you for your help !

Comment: Glad you figured it out.